# qs.strinigfy on qs.parse converts an array of single integer to an integer. how to fix the issue?

Tags: javascript, stringify

I am trying to stringify an object `{foo:[1]}` using `qs` library. And, put it in my URL. But, when I parse the query string, the object `{foo:[1]}` has been converted into `{foo:1}`. Code below -

```
import qs from "qs"; 

const str = qs.stringify({foo:[1]}; 
const parsed = qs.parse(str); 
console.log(parsed);
```

parsed =  `{foo:1}` instead of `{foo:[1]}` which was originally supplied to qs.stringify.
and i face this issue with an array of single element which is an integer. https://github.com/ljharb/qs/issues/315

Comment: I'm getting the right output, [check out this repl](https://repl.it/@ryeballar/YummyLumberingCompilers). What package version of `qs` are you using?

Comment: ok, thanks for this. I understood the issue. I was converting "false" to false, and "45" to 45 AFTER qs.parse() and in this !isNaN([1]) was getting satisfied bcoz JS converts [1]->"1"->1, and Number([1]) was converting [1] -> 1. By bad, again, thank you